# the vscode start terminial error with exit code 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, exit, launch

I start the vscode terminial, but get error, the detial is:

> The terminal process command '/usr/bin/bash' failed to launch (exit
>   code: 1)

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after running `/bin/bash -l` and an import of `/bin/bash` in my settings the terminal started working again.

you can test it in external terminal

Comment: In which setting? Can you explain little in detail?